# How to get custom product attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I added new attribute

> src/app/code/local/PACK/MODUL/sql/pack_modul_setup/mysql4-upgrade-2.1.6-2.1.7.php :

```
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'passhub_contract', array(
    'group'             => 'Pass',
    'sort_order'        => 50,
    'type'              => 'string',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'PassHub Contract Holder',
    'input'             => 'text',
    'input_renderer'    => '',
    'class'             => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'frontend_model'    => '',
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'option'            => array(),
    'frontend_class'    => 'validate-number',
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'apply_to'          => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL,
));

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'passhub_contract_id', array(
    'group'             => 'Pass',
    'sort_order'        => 50,
    'type'              => 'int',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'PassHub Contract Holder ID',
    'input'             => 'text',
    'input_renderer'    => '',
    'class'             => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'frontend_model'    => '',
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'option'            => array(),
    'frontend_class'    => 'validate-number',
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'apply_to'          => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_VIRTUAL,
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

At the admin panel it's ok. But if I try

> $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('product_id');

I haven't it. Where is my mistake? 
`$product->getAttributeText('passhub_contract');` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this code :

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$strPasshubContract = $_product->getPasshubContract();
```

or

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$strPasshubContract = $_product->getData('passhub_contract');
```